# Routing issue with redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

Is it possible to create this kind of route:
`"param1 / param2 / *"`

- where `*`, everything that comes after param1 / param2 and also I want a default for this, which will redirect always to `param1 / param2 /`?

```
Pseudocode:
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "AppController/Index/*",
            defaults: new { controller = "AppController", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Example:
`AppController / Index / test / qwe / 123` -> expect it to be redirected to `AppController / Index`

And also could this be solved in RouteConfig or should it be some rule in web.config?
Or other solution are welcome too :)

Comment: When you say redirect do you mean a 302?

Comment: @mjwills no need to load AppController/Index/test/qwe/123 such routes, under AppController/Index there is another app(angular), which has his own router. So by MVC I need always redirect * routes to the AppController/Index.

Comment: @mjwills what do you mean by 302?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+302+redirect You keep saying `redirect`, but you don't know what a 302 is. Which makes me think you want it _routed_ not _redirected_.

Comment: @mjwills 302 is just status and I dont understand why you are talking about it.
Again simple flow - user has a link, http://AppController/Index/test/qwe/123
I expect from MVC engine not to load such route and instantly redirect user to AppController/Index

Comment: What _exact_ URL do you expect to see in the browser?

Comment: @mjwills http://AppController/Index

Comment: Cool. So I'd suggest you need to 302 so that the browser redirects from `AppController/Index/test/qwe/123` to `AppController/Index`. Agree / disagree?

Comment: @mjwills agree, that is exactly my question

Comment: I'd suggest Googling for `maproute redirect asp.net mvc c#`.

Comment: @mjwills done, but didn`t find solution or some way to resolve this one and because of that I`m posting question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url: "AppController/Index/{.*}",

`{.*}` Simple regex fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in methods

```
...
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public void test(string id)
{
    return Ok(id);
}
```

uri:
localhost:{port}/api/test/{id}

Comment: I dont need this optional parametrs